# How to I make a Windows certificate exportable?

Tags: security, certificate, jailbreak

I'm looking for a tool or solution that would allow me make a certificate that is marked as non-exportable to be exportable.

I am aware about [Jailbreak](https://www.isecpartners.com/application-security-tools/jailbreak.html) tool but because the tool does not fully export the entire security chain I just want to mark this certificate as exportable and use the Windows own export option.

Comment: You can save the certificate and move it to another computer you just can't export the private key. As far as I know you can't change the export state of a private key

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this @sorin? I'm trying to use a code-signing certificate from godaddy and i can't generate the .pfx file because the certificate they gave me was marked as non-exportable.